# Laptop goes off (not shutdown), which log file should i check?

Tags: power-management

I have problem with my Lenovo x121e - goes off and i can't start it immediately again. I must  wait 3-5 min and then works again. CPU Temperature was okay, about 65°, HDD Temp too - 37°. Badblocks (only read mode) say, there are no bad sectors. Any ideas, what can cause the problem? Where can i find more info about the cause?

edit: the power cuts without shutdown or restart process

Comment: I've never heard of such a problem when heat *wasn't* a factor, but in regards to which log file to check I would try /var/log/syslog , there's almost always something useful in there.

Comment: By 'goes off (not shutdown)' do you mean that the power just cuts out with no shutdown process? If so you may want to include that in your description of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `last` command to have a look at the log which deals with shutdown and reboots.

Try the command

```
last -xwF
```

for which you would get something like this (this is my output)

```
manish   pts/2        :0               Thu Apr  5 19:09:33 2012   still logged in                      
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.2.0-21-generic Thu Apr  5 17:46:34 2012 - Thu Apr  5 21:25:50  2012  (03:39)    
reboot   system boot  3.2.0-21-generic Thu Apr  5 17:46:34 2012 - Thu Apr  5 21:25:50 2012  (03:39)    
manish   pts/2        :0.0             Thu Apr  5 02:12:38 2012 - Thu Apr  5 02:12:47 2012  (00:00)    
manish   pts/1        :0               Thu Apr  5 00:31:27 2012 - crash                     (17:15)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.2.0-21-generic Wed Apr  4 18:42:38 2012 - Thu Apr  5 17:46:34 2012  (23:03)    
reboot   system boot  3.2.0-21-generic Wed Apr  4 18:42:38 2012 - Thu Apr  5 21:25:50 2012 (1+02:43)   
manish   pts/5        :0               Wed Apr  4 00:31:25 2012 - crash                     (18:11)    
manish   pts/3        :0               Wed Apr  4 00:19:11 2012 - crash                     (18:23)    
manish   pts/2        :0               Wed Apr  4 00:18:15 2012 - crash                     (18:24)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.2.0-21-generic Tue Apr  3 19:29:27 2012 - Wed Apr  4 18:42:38 2012  (23:13)    
reboot   system boot  3.2.0-21-generic Tue Apr  3 19:29:27 2012 - Thu Apr  5 21:25:50  2012 (2+01:56)   
manish   pts/4        :0.0             Tue Apr  3 01:37:45 2012 - Tue Apr  3 01:57:44 2012  (00:19)    
manish   pts/3        :0               Mon Apr  2 23:39:22 2012 - crash                     (19:50)    
manish   pts/1        :0               Mon Apr  2 23:05:03 2012 - crash                     (20:24)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.2.0-21-generic Mon Apr  2 19:03:57 2012 - Tue Apr  3 19:29:27 2012 (1+00:25)   
reboot   system boot  3.2.0-21-generic Mon Apr  2 19:03:57 2012 - Thu Apr  5 21:25:50 2012 (3+02:21)   
shutdown system down  3.2.0-17-generic Mon Apr  2 08:54:27 2012 - Mon Apr  2 19:03:57 2012  (10:09)    
shutdown system down  3.2.0-17-generic Mon Apr  2 08:54:22 2012 - Mon Apr  2 08:54:27 2012  (00:00)    
runlevel (to lvl 0)   3.2.0-17-generic Mon Apr  2 08:53:40 2012 - Mon Apr  2 08:54:22 2012  (00:00)    
manish   pts/7        :0.0             Sun Apr  1 20:53:34 2012 - Mon Apr  2 02:28:21 2012  (05:34)    
manish   pts/5        :0               Sun Apr  1 16:00:45 2012 - Mon Apr  2 08:53:12 2012  (16:52)
```

You can grep through the entries

```
last -xwF | grep reboot

last -xwF | grep shutdown
```

Comment: there isn't shutdown or reboot process, just goes off.

Answer (score 1):

You should watch the `/var/log/dmesg` file, or the `/var/log/syslog`.